# C# 4.0 unlock image after creating BitmapImage

Tags: image, c#-4.0, bitmapimage

I am creating an BitmapImage from an existing image using:

```
BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
bmp.BeginInit();
bmp.UriSource = new Uri(jpegPath, UriKind.Relative);
bmp.EndInit();
```

After I have done this I want to delete the image from my hard drive, but it is locked.
Is there a way I can unlock it so it can be removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bmp.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;`

That will load the image into memory completely and won't leave a lock on the image file.

Answer (score 0):

JPG is still set as the source of existing object in your application. Try to set the source of BitmapImage to something else or remove it completely. Or create a copy of your JPG in memory.