# BitmapImage in WPF does lock file

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, bitmapimage, locked

I use:

```
Dim bmi As New BitmapImage(New Uri(fiInfo.FullName, UriKind.Absolute))
bmi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad
```

this does not [Use OnLoad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116260/c-4-0-unlock-image-after-creating-bitmapimage)
And file still is locked to overwrite on harddisk. Any idea how to unlock?

Regards

Comment: There are also memory issues to take a look at. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271891/net-memory-issues-loading-40-images-memory-not-reclaimed-potentially-due-to-l/6271982#6271982

Comment: Thanks. Do you want me to say, to not try to cache all file if not really possible with your link?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As shown in the question you link to, you'd need to call BeginInit and EndInit, like so as well as set the UriSource property:

```
Dim bmi As New BitmapImage()
bmi.BeginInit()
bmi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad
bmi.UriSource = New Uri(fiInfo.FullName, UriKind.Absolute)
bmi.EndInit()
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply also regarding my keywords and VB instead of C#! Works great now!

Comment: Is there a way to do this strictly using XAML.

Answer (score 9):

Read the `BitmapImage` from file and rewrite it with a `MemoryStream`:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
byte[] bytArray = File.ReadAllBytes(@"test.jpg");
ms.Write(bytArray, 0, bytArray.Length);ms.Position = 0;
bi.BeginInit();
bi.StreamSource = ms;
bi.EndInit();
image.Source = bi;
```

Comment: Thank you Navid for your quick reply. I see that will work that way as far as I see. I am using the `bmi.EndInit()` methode + `OnLoad
` now which is a little more simple in my case.

Comment: Now, who owns the MemoryStream object instance and is responsible for disposing it?

Comment: Anyway... How to unlock file and delete it?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and I solved using this method:
(it's a personalization of an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319447/release-handle-on-file-imagesource-from-bitmapimage))

```
    public static BitmapImage BitmapFromUri(Uri source)
    {
        var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.BeginInit();
        bitmap.UriSource = source;
        bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmap.EndInit();
        return bitmap;
    }
```

You can open the image like this:

```
BitmapImage bimg = BitmapFromUri(new Uri(some_URI));
```

And it releases the image immediatly after loading it.

Hope it can helps!

Answer (score 2):

```
BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri(filePath), BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
```

Comment: Best solution in 1 line. Thanks! I used MemoryStream before, but this looks more simple.