# file being used by another process

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

```
private void ButtonCustomarinfoEditClick(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      ByteToImage(fileName,bytesOfImage,fileSize);
    }   

private ImageSource ByteToImage(string fileName, byte[] bytesOfImage, int fileSize)
    {
        FileStream imageFilestream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        imageFilestream.Write(bytesOfImage, 0, fileSize);
        imageFilestream.Flush();
        imageFilestream.Close();
        imageFilestream.Dispose();
        BitmapImage myBitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        myBitmapImage.BeginInit();
        myBitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(fileName);
        myBitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = 200;
        myBitmapImage.EndInit();
        return myBitmapImage;
    }
```

When i click ButtonCustomarinfoEdit fist time then it work`s fine. But When i click second time then it throw this exception

Caught: "The process cannot access the file 'C:\20.jpg' because it is being used by another process." (System.IO.IOException)
Exception Message = "The process cannot access the file 'C:\20.jpg' because it is being used by another process.", Exception Type = "System.IO.IOException"

Comment: possible duplicate of [BitmapImage in WPF does lock file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430299/bitmapimage-in-wpf-does-lock-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your BitmapImage object keeps the file locked.

Just a small observation, please use the [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) like this:

```
using(FileStream imageFilestream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)) { 
        imageFilestream.Write(bytesOfImage, 0, fileSize); 
}
```

otherwise you might run into situations that your file will remain in use (if an exception will occur before you call the Close() method.