# Release handle on file. ImageSource from BitmapImage

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can I release the handle on this file?

img is of type System.Windows.Controls.Image

```
private void Load()
{
    ImageSource imageSrc = new BitmapImage(new Uri(filePath));
    img.Source = imageSrc;
    //Do Work
    imageSrc = null;
    img.Source = null;
    File.Delete(filePath); // File is being used by another process.
}
```

---

**Solution**

---

```
private void Load()
{
    ImageSource imageSrc = BitmapFromUri(new Uri(filePath));
    img.Source = imageSrc;
    //Do Work
    imageSrc = null;
    img.Source = null;
    File.Delete(filePath); // File deleted.
}



public static ImageSource BitmapFromUri(Uri source)
{
    var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    bitmap.BeginInit();
    bitmap.UriSource = source;
    bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmap.EndInit();
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: what are these 3 lines :     img.Source = imageSrc;
    //Do Work
    imageSrc = null;
    img.Source = null;

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG don't worry about them... bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad; is the magic part.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Found the answer on MSDN Forum.

> Bitmap stream is not closed unless caching option is set as
>   BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad. So you need something like this:
>
> ```
> public static ImageSource BitmapFromUri(Uri source)
> {
>     var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
>     bitmap.BeginInit();
>     bitmap.UriSource = source;
>     bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
>     bitmap.EndInit();
>     return bitmap;
> }
> ```
>
> And when you get an ImageSource using the method above, source file
>   will be immediately closed.

[see MSDN social forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/5b2270cb-f182-4f5f-a6c6-c78dfe4e3230/)

Comment: if I use this code is there any changes of Memory increase of the application?

Answer (score 1):

I kept running into issues with this on a particularly troubling image. The accepted answer did not work for me.

Instead, I used a stream to populate the bitmap:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
{
    bitmap.BeginInit();
    bitmap.StreamSource = fs;
    bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmap.EndInit();
}
```

This caused the file handle to be released.