# How to read image dimensions at C# wpf - there is no dispose method for BitmapImage

Tags: c#, wpf, image, .net-4.5, bitmapimage

With the way below i am able to read.

But there is no dispose method so i am not able to delete the file later.

So the below method is getting failed.

I could not come up with a proper solution.

Bitmap class is not recognized in C# 4.5 WPF application.

thank you

```
    DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\pokemon_files\images\");
    FileInfo[] subFiles = dInfo.GetFiles();

    BitmapImage myImg;
    foreach (var vrImage in subFiles)
    {
        string srFilePath = vrImage.FullName;
        System.Uri myUri = new Uri(srFilePath);
        myImg = new BitmapImage(myUri);

        if (myImg.Width < 50)
        {
            File.Delete(srFilePath);
            continue;
        }
     }
```

Comment: which error message do you get?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319447/release-handle-on-file-imagesource-from-bitmapimage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the error you get is caused by trying to delete the file which is currently in use
by the bitmap (I don't remember the exception name).

There is a solution to that, that is: making a byte stream.

```
byte[] imageData;

using(var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
using(var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fileStream))
{
    imageData = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)fileStream.Length);
}

var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
bitmap.BeginInit();
bitmap.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(imageData);
bitmap.EndInit();

//Now you can check the width & height, the file stream should be closed so you can
//delete the file.
```

[EDIT]
If you don't want to read the bytes by `BinaryReader`, there's always [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10038017/1180426) if you want to read all bytes from the file.

Comment: You should allways check the amount of bytes you receive from `ReadBytes` method.