# Out of memory exception while loading images from isolated storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, out-of-memory, bitmapimage

I am getting *`OutofMemoryException`* in this particular code.

```
public BitmapImage GetImage(int pageNo)
        {
            if (!this._isLoaded)
            {
                this.Load();
            }
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication().OpenFile(this.FileNames[pageNo], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
                image.SetSource(stream);            

                return image;

            }
        }
```

The out of memory exception is occuring at `image.SetSource(stream)` . I cant set the uri to `null` because I have to return the image.

What is the workaround for this? Help me here.

Comment: Please try the solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319447/release-handle-on-file-imagesource-from-bitmapimage because it is possible, that you close your stream before it is initialized.

Comment: I cannot find BeginInit, CacheOption , EndInit properties for my Bitmap Image. I am doing this for wp 7.

Comment: How big is the image?

Comment: @AntonSizikov 1060x1500 is the resolution of the image.

Comment: Does in happen on first call? I mean, what is the workflow? Do you create this image once?

Comment: @AntonSizikov I am maintaining a cache of 6 such images in a List.So i can say not one , At the max six images.

Comment: Have a look at this page, http://blogs.developpeur.org/kookiz/archive/2013/02/17/wpdev-memory-leak-with-bitmapimage.aspx  hope it will help you

Comment: @AntonSizikov I read the link.Thanks, But I am not very clear regarding the usage of the Dispose(image) method given in the link. How and where should i add it in my code. Since i have to return the image i cannot make it null.

Comment: I think that you show this images, don't you? So, you have an <Image> tag in xaml, you load one image, then you load second. Before loading the second image you need to dispose first image.

Comment: @AntonSizikov I resolved the issue finally . As your suggestion i have made the cleared the uri. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this list of bitmap images.

```
 private List<BitmapImage> _images = new List<BitmapImage>();
```

I cleared the uri while leaving the page.

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
            this.DataContext = null;
            foreach (var obj in this._images)
            {
                if (obj != null)
                {
                    obj.ClearValue(BitmapImage.UriSourceProperty);
                }

            }
```