# App crashes while trying to bind the Isolated Storage Image

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In my application I am using the below mentioned helper method for binding my Isolated storage image to Image control. I got this helper method from the link "[Binding Image stored in the Isolated Storage to Image Control in Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102651/binding-image-stored-in-the-isolated-storage-to-image-control-in-windows-phone/16103494#comment23023219_16103494)"

```
public class IsoStoreImageSource : DependencyObject
{
public static void SetIsoStoreFileName(UIElement element, string value)
{
    element.SetValue(IsoStoreFileNameProperty, value);
}
public static string GetIsoStoreFileName(UIElement element)
{
    return (string)element.GetValue(IsoStoreFileNameProperty);
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsoStoreFileName.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsoStoreFileNameProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsoStoreFileName", typeof(string), typeof(IsoStoreImageSource), new PropertyMetadata("", Changed));

private static void Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Image img = d as Image;

    if (img != null)
    {
        var path = e.NewValue as string;
        SynchronizationContext uiThread = SynchronizationContext.Current;

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            using (var isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                if (isoStore.FileExists(path))
                {
                    var stream = isoStore.OpenFile(path, System.IO.FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    uiThread.Post(_ =>
                    {
                        var _img = new BitmapImage();
                        _img.SetSource(stream);
                        img.Source = _img;
                    }, null);
                }
            }
        });               
    }
}
```

}

I am using this inside a ListBox control. And if try with default library images everything will work as expected. But if I try with the images with large size( taken through device camera ) the app crashes.

And here is the exception what I am getting

An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

stack trace

at MS.Internal.FrameworkCallbacks.NotifyManagedDebuggerOnNativeOOM()
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.BitmapSource_SetSource(BitmapSource bitmapSource, CValue& byteStream)
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.SetSourceInternal(Stream streamSource)
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage.SetSourceInternal(Stream streamSource)
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.SetSource(Stream streamSource)
   at MyaPP.Common.IsoStoreImageSource.<>c__DisplayClass4.<>c__DisplayClass6.b__1(Object _)

Comment: How many images are you in your list view? How big are they? Can you run memory analysis on your app (`Debug -> Start Windows Phone Application Analysis -> Profiling -> Memory` in Visual Studio) and post your results?

Comment: Try to use LongListSelector as Flat List

Comment: @Haspemulator  : The issue is mentioned here "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15700340/out-of-memory-exception-while-loading-images-from-isolated-storage", "http://blogs.developpeur.org/kookiz/archive/2013/02/17/wpdev-memory-leak-with-bitmapimage.aspx", How I can resolve this issue with your implementation.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. @Haspemulator , I perform memory profiling and got a similar response mentioned in the above blog. Can you please update a solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The caching within the `ListBox` might be taking up your memory and this is especially noticeable with larger images. I'm not familiar with the helper method you've posted but try adding this.

```
if (img != null)
{
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = img.Source as BitmapImage;
    bitmapImage.UriSource = null;
    img.Source = null;

    //rest of the code ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it took some time for me to return to this issue. I'll share my findings here, but I'm not considering them a real answer to the issue, but rather a workaround. However, I hope it will help somebody.

First I want to confirm `OutOfMemoryException` happens in certain circumstances. But, surprisingly, it depends on the page layout you're using. In fact, if your layout involves `StackPanel`, you'll have an exception. I guess, it comes down to the fact how `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride` methods are implemented in `StackPanel` (though I may be completely wrong here). It looks like when `ListBox` is a child to `StackPanel`, it tries to load all of the images before display. This, of course, causes the memory leak.

On the other hand, if you use something like `Grid` as a parent for list of images, then there's no such exceptions, and the memory load is reasonable.

Here's page layout that worked for me:

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding IsoStorePics}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image local:IsoStoreImageSource.IsoStoreFileName="{Binding Path}" Margin="5"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

This is the best answer I have for you now. Please let me know if it helped.

Comment: I think it is not the issue. I tried something like this too,    <Grid  Height="350" Width="400" Margin="70,0,70,0" x:Name="Container1">
                                <Grid.Background>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ImageCollection[0]}" Stretch="Uniform" AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Center"/>
                                </Grid.Background>

Comment: And also I tried the above method u mentioned, but the result is same.. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this, Stream object will automatically disposed.

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{                               
     if (iso.FileExists(imagePath))
     {
         using (Stream imagestream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, iso))
         {
               BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
               bmp.SetSource(imagestream);
               imgControl.Source = bmp;
         }
     }
}
```