# External Exception was unhandled. A generic error occurred in GDI+. only on second call

Tags: c#, gdi+

I created a WPF project which has a settings window as main window and from there I open a game window. When opening the game window, the following code creates one long image strip out of several images.

```
var target = new System.Drawing.Bitmap((int)width, (int)height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
var graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(target);
graphics.CompositingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceOver;

int i = 0;
foreach (Image img in images)
{
     System.Drawing.Image drawingImg = ConvertWpfImageToImage(img);
     System.Drawing.Bitmap source = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(drawingImg);
     graphics.DrawImage(source, i, 0);
     i += 320;
}
target.Save(@".\resources\images\conveyerBeltSymbols\bigPicture.png");
```

This seems to be no problem (although I am saving a bitmap image as png, I know that) at the first time but when I close the second window and try to open it again (without closing the first window too) I get `External Exception was unhandled. A generic error occurred in GDI+`.

I tried adding `Dispose()` to both `graphics` and `target` and also tried to add `ImageFormat.Png` to the `target.Save` method but nothing worked for me.

Has anyone got a solution?

Comment: Are you using `Image.FromFile` at any point to load the `bigPicture.png` image? That method will keep the file locked until your process exits, which would prevent the `Save` method from overwriting it.

Comment: `slider.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@".\resources\images\conveyerBeltSymbols\bigPicture.png", UriKind.Relative));` is how I "load" the picture. I also tried setting `slider.ImageSource = null` at window closing but that didn't help either

Comment: That will keep the file locked. Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6430416/124386) - it's in VB, but it should be fairly simple to translate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading the picture using the `new BitmapImage(Uri)` constructor will keep the file locked. Try using:

```
var image = new BitmapImage();
image.BeginInit();
image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
image.UriSource = new Uri(@".\resources\images\conveyerBeltSymbols\bigPicture.png", UriKind.Relative);
image.EndInit();

slider.ImageSource = image;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you are properly `using` or calling `Dispose()` on each of the GDI objects... Including your `Bitmap` and `Image`. This should resolve your issues. It's likely you're not releasing unmanaged resources properly.

Comment: As I wrote, I already tried `target.Dispose()` and `graphics.Dispose` after I save the Bitmap but that didn't solve it.