# Delete Image Issue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# 4.0 unlock image after creating BitmapImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116260/c-sharp-4-0-unlock-image-after-creating-bitmapimage)

I have this code to create an Image file in WPF.

```
var newimage = new System.Windows.Controls.Image
{
    Stretch = Stretch.Fill,
    StretchDirection = StretchDirection.Both,
    Width = Width,
    Height = Height
};

var logo2 = new BitmapImage();
logo2.BeginInit();
logo2.UriSource = uri;
logo2.EndInit();
newimage.Source = logo2;
```

After this some process have to delete ol file and create a new one but I'm facing an error

> "Cannot delete file because it is being used by another process"

What should I do to fix this issue?

Thank you!

---

**P.S.**

I delete the file using this:

```
try
{
    if (File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        File.Delete(fileName);
        Debug.WriteLine("FILE MANAGER: File " + fileName + " has been deleted.");
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: May you please provide how are you trying to delete the file?

Comment: @PicrofoEGY Done. Pls have a look.

Comment: Thank you for providing the information. Though, it was not yet possible to indicate where the problem occur. Can you please provide more information about `fileName`? :)

Comment: @PicrofoEGY it is the absolute path to that file.

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand your last comment :(

Comment: Did you try using Process Explorer to check which process actually uses your image ?

Comment: @PicrofoEGY the path is like C:\Folder\Image.png

Comment: @PicrofoEGY May be I have to use USING() somehow?

Comment: @Peretz Sorry, but I do not really know. I can't help using the information provided. Maybe you can try [Sisyphe's suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/17789511). I'm really sorry :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use:

```
var logo2 = new BitmapImage();
logo2.BeginInit();
logo2.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
logo2.UriSource = uri;
logo2.EndInit();
```

Comment: Can I just read this file into memory and dont lock the disk image file?

Comment: @Peretz - Possibly, but what I have above is generally better as you would have to figure out who disposes of the MemoryStream. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430299/bitmapimage-in-wpf-does-lock-file/6430416#6430416